# how to save application data in android

Tags: android, android-studio

hi I want to build android app doing the next:

enter home that contains carousel to choose the topic then when user choose the topic that he wants navigate to another activity and import quotes to the activities. 
 my question is: 
what's the best & simplest  way to save my quotes at ??

Comment: i think simplest and fastest for learn is SharedPreferences , but also you can create databases like Sqlite or Realm. Also if your quotes is constant , you can use strings.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the number of quotes in the application for each of the topic. If you have a relatively small number of quotes then they can be stored as a string array in your code and can be used to populate a ListView. Consider the code below:

```
String[] quotes = {"Today is a wonderful day", "Tomorrow is going to be wonderful"};
ListView listView; 
// Set the Id for the ListView
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
// set the adapter
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quotes));
```

But if you store a large number of quotes, then I'd suggest you use Android's implementation of SQLite Database. More from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)
This will store the quotes in the phone's local storage.

Another way to do this would be but requires an active internet connection is using Android MySql Database hosted on a hosting website. I suggest you watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdyZKewSwFg) video.

I'd suggest in any case the best way to store the quotes would be to use an Android SQLite database.